Logarithm approximation loses solution
I was doing an exercise in which I had to plot by hand a function.
The function was $$f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{3x - 1}\right)$$
which I rewrote into $$f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{3} - \ln\left(3x - 1\right)$$
As the argument of log needs to be $>0$.  I stated that the domain of the function was $$f(x) ∈R, ∀x>1/3$$
However once I finished the exercise I wrote the function on desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to verify my working out and found out that i missed completely the part on the left. As you can see from the image the blue and black function overlap for $$x>1/3$$ however only the black function shows the negative part. Why?


Make $x=-1000$ in the first expression. What do you get ?

The problem arises when you divide (multiply) two negative numbers. In general, $\ln ab = \ln a + \ln b$, but only when $\ln a$ and $\ln b$ are defined. That's why you cannot really make
$$
\ln (-10) + \ln(-10) = \ln (-10)(-10) = \ln 100
$$
or something similar.

$\ln(\dfrac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln (b)$ holds only when $a,b>0$. For the case $a,b<0$, $\ln(\dfrac{a}{b})$ can be written as $\ln(-a)-\ln (-b)$.
Before rewriting the function, the domain is $\dfrac{a}{b}>0$, or equivalently, $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$.
For $a,b>0$, as you said, the domain is $]1/3,+\infty[$. But for $a,b<0$, the domain is $]-\infty,0[$. So the whole domain is the union of them.

The simplifications you made are only valid when all the expressions are well defined. The original expression and the one that you obtained coincide when $x > \frac 13$, but the original one is also defined for $x<0$.
